# How can I add a style to specific items in my ng-repeat list?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, sass, addclass

I am using Ionic which is using Angular.js

My html page has a ng-init which calls a function from my controller. the function hits a service which goes to the database to retrieve all the songs.

```
    $scope.getAllSongs = function(){  
      songService.getAllSongs()  
      .success(function(data){
         //the data is an array of songs
         //songs get organize by being pushed to other arrays the html page uses

       **//for loop
         // if(x[i].visibility === false
           //change the background color to red **
       }
    })
```

On the html file, I use ng-repeat to show the items in the specific array like so.

```
 <ion-item ng-repeat="song in ASongs | orderBy:'title'">
    <div class="row responsive-sm">
       <div>
          <a>
            <h2>{{song.title}}</h2>
          </a>
       </div>
    </div>
 </ion-item>
```

the songs in the ASongs array all have a property called "visibility" which is a boolean. ng-repeat will display the list of items in the ASongs Array. Now I'm trying to figure out how to change the background color of all the songs with a visibility that are false.

Comment: You can use ng-style ng-style="expression" . https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle

Comment: try using `ng-class = "{background_color: song.visibility === false}"`, here `background_color` is the css class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive.

CSS :

```
.background-with-false {
   background-color : your-color;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div ng-class"{ 'background-with-false' : song.visibility === false }" class="row responsive-sm">
       <div>
          <a>
            <h2>{{ song.title }}</h2>
          </a>
       </div>
</div>
```

You can also [ngStyle](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle)